# 3D Array to 3D std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I replaced a 3D array with a 3D std::vector in my code function and it's entering a infinite loop .Could you give me a hint,I really need to use a vector instead an array.Thanks:)
My initial code was:

```
//arr is a 3D array of a sudoku table,the 3 rd dimension is for keeping values 0 to 13  
//for a cell, and when I assign values I start from index 1 to 12

bool sol(int arr[12][12][13]) {
int row,col;

if(!find_empty(arr,row,col)) return true;

for(int i=1;i< 12;i++) { //for digits 1 to 12
    if(is_working(arr,row,col,arr[row][col][i]) ) {   //if i can put the value in a cell
        arr[row][col][0] = arr[row][col][i];  //replace the first element for a cell with that value
     //here I want to use vector because I want to use an ac3 algorithm 
     //and remove those values that not satisfy constraints and shrink domain size having less values to verify with backtrack

        if(sol(arr)) return true;

        arr[row][col][0] = 0;
    }
}

return false;//if not backtrack
}
```

I replace **arr** with:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > vec;
vec.resize(12);
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
vec[i].resize(12);
for(int j=0;j<12;j++)
{
    vec[i][j].resize(13);
    for(int k=0;k<13;k++)
        vec[i][j][k]=table[i][j][k];
   }
} 


bool sol(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >& vec) {
int row,col;

if(!find_empty(vec,row,col)) return true;

for(int i=1;i< vec[row][col].size();i++) {//for remainig values in domain
    if(is_working(vec,row,col,vec[row][col][i]) ) {//same as above but having less values to verify for
        vec[row][col][0] = vec[row][col][i];

        if(sol(vec)) return true;

        vec[row][col][0] = 0;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

and now it's entering a infinite loop!The initial code has no errors,it's a simple backtracking.The problem appears after I replace **arr** with **vec**.Could you give me some advice on how to replace 3D **arr** with an 3D vector

Comment: *"infinite loop at compiling"* ehmmm what do you mean with this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to start your loop with index `1`?

Comment: `vector::resize` changes the actual content of the vector by inserting or erasing elements from it

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing where the infinite loop occurs ?

Comment: Yes it occurs in the for

Comment: From here it looks alright, except I wouldn't use the `resize`'s but instead initialize the vectors with the correct size. We need more to go on. Although when you say that "it happens in the for" that makes me assume that `vec[row][col].size()` returns some incredibly large number, which would bring us back to "are `row` and `col` within the bounds of the vector?"

Comment: If its looping in the for loop, and not the recursive sol call, you should be able to easily see what is preventing the loop from terminating. I would pay particular attention to the return value of vec[row][col].size() when you are in the infinite loop.

Comment: Also, assuming your changes to is_working() or find_empty() haven't broken it, the only difference I see is that originally you compared i to 12 for your for loop, but now you compare it to the vector size. Which lends credence to the possibility that the size isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: Your original loop goes from [1, 12[, but your new loop goes from [1, 13[, since all the 3rd-level vectors have a `size()` of 13 (if I read your initialization code correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I used a matrix of vectors instead a 3D vector and it works great :D

maybe this better for 3d one, 4x4x4

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> matrix;

matrix.resize(4, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(4,std::vector<double(4)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. If you can also post the code for is_working and find_empty, then we would be able to see how you are getting the values of row and column.
I would have put this as a comment but being a new member and not having enough reputations, I have to put this as an answer. I'll edit it once you share the code for is_working() and find_empty()

Comment: The problem was not in the code.The problem was at the data structure,3D vector somehow wasn't modifying his elements leading to an inconsistency in the algorithm

Comment: It must have been a problem with the code or how you were setting the values of the vector. But I am glad that you got it working one way or other.